# Storing IP addresses - varchar(45) vs varbinary(16)

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2012, nonclustered-index, sql-clr

I am going to create a table with two fields - `ID` as `BIGINT` and `IPAddress` as either `varchar(45)` or `varbinary(16)`. The idea is to store all unique IP addresses and use a reference `ID` instead the actual `IP address` in other tables.

Generally, I am going to create a stored procedure that is returning the `ID` for given `IP address` or (if the address was not found) insert the address and return the generated `ID`.

I am expecting to have many records (I cannot tell exactly how many), but I need the stored procedure above to be executed as fast as possible. So, I am wondering how to stored the actual IP address - in text or bytes format. Which is going to be better?

I have already written `SQL CLR` functions for transforming IP address bytes to string and the reverse, so transformation is not an issue (working with both `IPv4` and `IPv6`).

I guess I need to create an index to optimize the search, but I am not sure should I include the `IP address` field to the clustered index, or to create a separate index and with which type the search will be faster?

Comment: For IPv4 at least, why not 4 tinyints? Then they're actually human readable and you don't have to perform any conversions. You can also create all kinds of persisted computed columns to represent specific types of searches (exact match, subnet, etc).

Comment: If it the case was only for `IPv4` I guess I would convert the address to `INT` and used the field as index key. But for `IPv6` I need to use two `BIGINT` fields and I prefer to store the value in one field - seems to me more natural.

Comment: Still don't understand why INT instead of 4 TINYINTs? Same storage, easier debugging, less nonsense, IMHO. If you have two completely different types with different validation and meaning, why do they need to use the same column? If you are betting that a single column is simpler, why not just use SQL_VARIANT, then you don't have to worry about anything. You can store dates and strings and numbers and everybody can have a big party in one gigantic, useless column...

Comment: Where are the IP Addresses coming from? Will they ever include the mask/subnet (i.e. 10.10.10.1/124)? I have seen this come through from web server logs and does not translate easily to BIGINT (INT won't work as the calculation requires an unsigned INT, unless of course, you incorporate that normalization to assume 0 is really -2.14xxxx billion). I guess the subnet mask could just be an additional TINYINT field. But I do understand wanting to store as BIGINT if wanting to match that up to a DB of latitude/longitude to map them out. But as Aaron mentioned, that can be a persisted computed col.

Answer (score 13):

> how to stored the actual IP address - in text or bytes format. Which is going to be better?

Since "text" here refers to `VARCHAR(45)` and "bytes" refers to `VARBINARY(16)`, I would say: *neither*.

Given the following information (from [Wikipedia article on IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Address_representation)):

> **Address representation**
>   The 128 bits of an IPv6 address are represented in 8 groups of 16 bits each. Each group is written as 4 hexadecimal digits and the groups are separated by colons (:). The address 2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:ff00:0042:8329 is an example of this representation.
>
> For convenience, an IPv6 address may be abbreviated to shorter notations by application of the following rules, where possible.
>
> - One or more leading zeroes from any groups of hexadecimal digits are removed; this is usually done to either all or none of the leading zeroes. For example, the group 0042 is converted to 42.
> - Consecutive sections of zeroes are replaced with a double colon (::). The double colon may only be used once in an address, as multiple use would render the address indeterminate. RFC 5952 recommends that a double colon must not be used to denote an omitted single section of zeroes.[41]
>
> An example of application of these rules:
>
> Initial address: 2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:ff00:0042:8329
>           After removing all leading zeroes in each group: 2001:db8:0:0:0:ff00:42:8329
>           After omitting consecutive sections of zeroes: 2001:db8::ff00:42:8329

I would start by using 8 `VARBINARY(2)` fields to represent the 8 groups. The fields for Groups 5 - 8 should be `NULL` as they will only be used for IPv6 addresses. The fields for Groups 1 - 4 should be `NOT NULL` as they will be used for both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

By keeping each group independent (as opposed to combining them into either a `VARCHAR(45)` or a `VARBINARY(16)` or even two `BIGINT` fields) you get two main benefits:

1. It is much easier to reconstruct the address into any particular representation. Otherwise, in order to replace consecutive groups of zeroes with (::) you would have to parse it out. Keeping them separate allows for simple `IF` / `IIF` / `CASE` statements to facilitate this.
2. You will save a ton of space on IPv6 addresses by enabling either `ROW COMPRESSION` or `PAGE COMPRESSION`. Since both types of COMPRESSION will allow for fields that are `0x00` to take up 0 bytes, all of those groups of zeroes will now not cost you anything. On the other hand, if you stored the example address from above (in the Wikipedia quote), then the 3 sets of all zeroes in the middle would take up their full amount of space (unless you were doing the `VARCHAR(45)` and went with the reduced notation, but that might not work well for indexing and would require special parsing to reconstruct it to the full format, so let's assume that is not an option ;-).

---

IF you need to capture the Network, create a `TINYINT` field for that called, um, `[Network]` :-)

For more info on the Network value, here is some info from another [Wikipedia article on the IPv6 address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Networks):

> **Networks**
>
> An IPv6 network uses an address block that is a contiguous group of IPv6 addresses of a size that is a power of two. The leading set of bits of the addresses are identical for all hosts in a given network, and are called the network's address or routing *prefix*.
>
> Network address ranges are written in CIDR notation. A network is denoted by the first address in the block (ending in all zeroes), a slash (/), and a decimal value equal to the size in bits of the prefix. For example, the network written as 2001:db8:1234::/48 starts at address 2001:db8:1234:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000 and ends at 2001:db8:1234:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff.
>
> The routing prefix of an interface address may be directly indicated with the address by CIDR notation. For example, the configuration of an interface with address 2001:db8:a::123 connected to subnet 2001:db8:a::/64 is written as 2001:db8:a::123/64.

---

For indexing, I would say create a Non-Clustered index on the 8 Group fields, and possibly the Network field if you decide to include that.

---

End result should be something like the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [IPAddress]
(
  IPAddressID INT          NOT NULL IDENTITY(-2147483648, 1),
  Group8      VARBINARY(2) NULL, -- IPv6 only, NULL for IPv4
  Group7      VARBINARY(2) NULL, -- IPv6 only, NULL for IPv4
  Group6      VARBINARY(2) NULL, -- IPv6 only, NULL for IPv4
  Group5      VARBINARY(2) NULL, -- IPv6 only, NULL for IPv4
  Group4      VARBINARY(2) NOT NULL, -- both
  Group3      VARBINARY(2) NOT NULL, -- both
  Group2      VARBINARY(2) NOT NULL, -- both
  Group1      VARBINARY(2) NOT NULL, -- both
  Network     TINYINT      NULL
);

ALTER TABLE [IPAddress]
  ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_IPAddress]
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  (IPAddressID ASC)
  WITH (FILLFACTOR = 100, DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_IPAddress_Groups]
  ON [IPAddress] (Group1 ASC, Group2 ASC, Group3 ASC, Group4 ASC,
         Group5 ASC, Group6 ASC, Group7 ASC, Group8 ASC, Network ASC)
  WITH (FILLFACTOR = 100, DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE);
```

Notes:

- I recognize that you plan on using `BIGINT` for the ID field, but do you really expect to capture more than 4,294,967,295 unique values? If so then just change the field to be BIGINT and you can then even change the seed value to be 0. But otherwise you are better off using INT and starting with the minimum value so that you can make use of the entire range of that datatype.
- If desired, you can add one or more NONpersisted Computed Columns to this table to return text representations of the IPAddress.
- The Group* fields are arranged purposefully going *down*, from 8 to 1, in the table so that doing `SELECT *` will return the fields in the expected order. But the index has them going *up*, from 1 to 8, as that is how they are filled out.
- An example (unfinished) of a computed column to represent the values in text form is:

  ```sql
  ALTER TABLE [IPAddress]
    ADD TextAddress AS (
  IIF([Group8] IS NULL,
      -- IPv4
      CONCAT(CONVERT(TINYINT, [Group4]), '.', CONVERT(TINYINT, [Group3]), '.',
        CONVERT(TINYINT, [Group2]), '.', CONVERT(TINYINT, [Group1]),
        IIF([Network] IS NOT NULL, CONCAT('/', [Network]), '')),
      -- IPv6
      LOWER(CONCAT(
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), [Group8], 2), ':', CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), [Group7], 2), ':',
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), [Group6], 2), ':', CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), [Group5], 2), ':',
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), [Group4], 2), ':', CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), [Group3], 2), ':',
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), [Group2], 2), ':', CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), [Group1], 2),
        IIF([Network] IS NOT NULL, CONCAT('/', [Network]), '')
       ))
     ) -- end of IIF
  );
  ```

  Test:

  ```sql
  INSERT INTO IPAddress VALUES (127, 0, 0, 0, 4, 22, 222, 63, NULL); -- IPv6
  INSERT INTO IPAddress VALUES (27, 10, 1234, 0, 45673, 200, 1, 6363, 48); -- IPv6
  INSERT INTO IPAddress VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 192, 168, 2, 63, NULL); -- v4
  INSERT INTO IPAddress VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 192, 168, 137, 29, 16); -- v4

  SELECT [IPAddressID], [Group8], [Group1], [Network], [TextAddress]
  FROM IPAddress ORDER BY [IPAddressID];
  ```

  Result:

  ```
  IPAddressID   Group8   Group1   Network  TextAddress
  -----------   ------   ------   -------  ---------------------
  -2147483646   0x007F   0x003F   NULL     007f:0000:0000:0000:0004:0016:00de:003f
  -2147483645   0x001B   0x18DB   48       001b:000a:04d2:0000:b269:00c8:0001:18db/48
  -2147483644   NULL     0x003F   NULL     192.168.2.63
  -2147483643   NULL     0x001D   16       192.168.137.29/16
  ```

Comment: For SQL Server 2005, would defining the columns as `VARDECIMAL` over `VARBINARY` since `DATA_COMPRESSION` isn't available?

Comment: @SolomonRutzky Thank you for the detailed explanation. I'm curious, how would I search between address ranges? For example, I have a data vendor providing IP Geolocation data in the form of a start and end IP address. I need to find which range a given IP falls in.

Comment: @JWeezy You are welcome :). How are the start and end IP addresses being stored? Are you using IPv4 or v6 addresses?

Comment: @SolomonRutzky Both. IPv4 isn't a problem because I can store it as an integer. Unfortunately, there is no 128 bit integer or number related data type in SQL Server large enough to handle it. So, for IPv6 I am storing it in VARBINARY(16) and then I use the BETWEEN operator to search between ranges. But, I am getting multiple results on IP ranges, which I do not think are correct. I would like to use the same data type for both IPv4 and IPv6 if possible.

Comment: @JWeezy I was going to suggest `BINARY(16)` ;-). Can you please give me an example with a start / end range and at least two rows that you get back, one valid and at least one invalid? It might be that VARbinary shortens some values.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky

IP to search: 2600:1011:b152:d4aa:b158:af57:d0d8:ef6d
IPHex to search: 0x323630303A313031313A623135323A64

IP Start 1:   2600:100:400:0:0:0:0:0
IPHex Start 1: 0x323630303A3130303A3430303A303A30
IP End 1: 2600:108:b155:b127:9587:c929:29ab:94f0
IPHex End 1: 0x323630303A3130383A623135353A6231

IP Start 2: 2600:1011:b150:0:0:0:0:0
IPHex Start 2: 0x323630303A313031313A623135303A30
Ip End 2: 2600:1011:b15f:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
IPHex End 2: 0x323630303A313031313A623135663A66

When I use an online integer converter, this actually does not provide a correct result

Comment: @SolomonRutzky IPv6 integer converter: https://www.ipaddressguide.com/ipv6-to-decimal

Comment: @SolomonRutzky Brilliant! The CONVERT to VARBINARY(16) is getting caught up in the truncation benefit that IPv6 offers. 
The following yield different results: SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(16), '2600:100:400:0:0:0:0:0')
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(16), '2600:100:400::')
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(16), '2600:0100:0400:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000')

Any thoughts on how to handle that?

Comment: @JWeezy I think something is amiss with your conversion to hex. For the IP to search, if the string is `2600:1011:b152:d4aa:b158:af57:d0d8:ef6d`, then shouldn't the hex be: `0x26001011b152d4aab158af57d0d8ef6d`? Just remove the colons because it's already a hex specification. Not sure how you are getting `0x323630303A313031313A623135323A64`. Also that tool converts to `DECIMAL(38, 0)`, not any integer type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90263/discussion-between-solomon-rutzky-and-j-weezy).

Comment: @SolomonRutzky SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(16), '2600:1011:b152:d4aa:b158:af57:d0d8:ef6d')
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(16), '26001011b152d4aab158af57d0d8ef6d')

That is how I am getting the HEX values.

Answer (score 2):

Smaller is always going to be faster.  With smaller values you can fit more of them into a single page, therefore less IO, potentially shallower B-Trees etc.

All other things (translation overhead, readability, compatibility, CPU load, index sargability etc.)  being equal, of course.